# Who was the owner of the house where Jesus and his disciples had the Last Supper and why did he consent

Tags: gospel-of-luke, passover

To clarify, by *host* I am referring to the owner of the house in which the Last Supper took place.

As is related in Luke 22, Jesus sent His disciples to seek out a man carrying a jug, follow him to a certain house, and to ask the owner of that house where He and disciples were to eat the Passover.

I'm curious to know how the owner's consent to this was obtained. Did he recognize the disciples as being Jesus' followers, or was it the custom of people with room to spare to allow guests to eat the Passover in their houses?

I'm especially interested in contemporary records that can shed some light on this.

If history is silent on this question, that is an acceptable answer as well.

Comment: According to Catholic tradition, this question seems to be answerable.